# Can processes can share variable in android?

Tags: android

I use android:process for my service in AndroidManifest.xml
But i have to share variable with original process(main gui).

I know sharing memory between processes is not possible. So i have to use something like shared memory.

So android:process is also not possible to share variable?
Even though static variable?

Answer (score 0):

jsut sharing data is possible via

String data="whatever you want to call you database"

```
context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(data, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).get("variableName")
 ... .set("variableName","variable");
```

if you also want to react to events:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent("action_value").putExtra("key","value"));
```

and

IntentFilter iFilter=new IntentFilter();
iFilter.add("action_value") //necessary whitelist per receiver

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                //do Stuffs
            }
        },iFilter);
```